How defining metrics to use other datetime field in request?
Reading https://nova.laravel.com/docs/metrics/defining-metrics.html#value-metrics docs
in Laravel 10 / nova 4.27 app I added metrics with command :
php artisan nova:value OrdersCompleted

i need to calc only completed orders by completed_by_manager_at field.
Order model has scope :
public function scopeOnlyCompleted($query)
{
    return $query->where($this->table . '.status', OrderStatusEnum::COMPLETED);
}

and in app/Nova/Metrics/OrdersCompleted.php I modified :
class OrdersCompleted extends Value
{
    /**
     * Calculate the value of the metric.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->count($request, Order::onlyCompleted());
    }

Checking sql I see :
   SELECT count(`orders`.`id`)     AS aggregate
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE `orders`.`status` = 'O'     AND `orders`.`created_at` between '2024-01-01 00:00:00'     AND '2024-10-28 05:38:01'

In the docs I did not find how can I instead created_at field to use completed_by_manager_at field ?
MODIFIES # 1:
In order modal I added scope :
public function scopeGetCompletedByManagerAtBetweenDates($query, datetime $date1 = null, datetime $date2 = null): Builder
{
    if( !empty($date1) and !empty($date2)) { // THESE conditions are false
        \Log::info('$date1::');
        \Log::info($date1);
        $query->whereBetween($this->table . '.completed_by_manager_at', [$date1, $date2]);
    }
    return $query;
}

and use this scope in my OrdersCompleted metrix class :
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
{
    \Log::info( '-1 OrdersCompleted $request->all()::' . print_r( $request->all(), true  ) );

    return $this->count($request, Order::onlyCompleted()->getCompletedByManagerAtBetweenDates());
}

In logs I see thaht $request->all() have values :
[timezone] => UTC
[range] => 30

How can I calc days of range for getCompletedByManagerAtBetweenDates method ?

Please read MODIFIES # 1:

Looking at the docs for the count() method:
/**
 * Return a value result showing the growth of an count aggregate over time.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|class-string<\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>  $model
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression|string|null  $column
 * @param  string|null  $dateColumn
 * @return \Laravel\Nova\Metrics\ValueResult
 */
public function count($request, $model, $column = null, $dateColumn = null) {
    return $this->aggregate($request, $model, 'count', $column, $dateColumn);
}

The 4th parameter can specify which column to use for the date aggregation. 
As such, try:
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request) {
    return $this->count($request, Order::onlyCompleted(), null, 'completed_by_manager_at');
}


Thanks! Could you please explain what for  3rd  string|null  $dateColumn param ?

The 3rd parameter is the column used in the count query. Looking at your original query when a null value is provided it uses the id - SELECT count(orders.id). This column should be equal to the unique_key of the table -- which by default is usually id. You only need to provide a value if you want to override id being used.
